# Agregar varias filas a DataGridView desde un textbox que escanea código de barras vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, sql-server-2012, dataset

Bien. Hace algunos días que no puedo solucionar mi problema.
Estoy creando un PDV, y en el form ventas, leo un ID de producto desde un textbox en el evento TextChanged y me agrega el producto por el ID ingresado. El problema es cuando ingreso un segundo ID, el primer producto se borra y me agrega este último mencionado y así sucesivamente, solo se agrega uno al DGV.

EN una clase (fventas) creo una Public Function:

```
    Public Function agregarProductosaVenta() As DataTable

    Try
        'llamo a mi conexión:
        conectado()
        cmd = New SqlCommand("PROCEDIMIENTO ALMACENADO CREADO EN SQL")
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Connection = cnn

        cmd.Parameters.Clear()
        'busco desde el textbox en mi form ventas el ID del producto el cual
        'quiero ingresar
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cod_barras", frmventas.txtCodBarras.Text)

        If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery Then
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            da.Fill(dt)

            'le doy nombre a mis columnas tal y como quiero que aparezcan en mi DGV
            'que después sería mi ticket
            dt.Columns(0).ColumnName = "Producto"
            dt.Columns(1).ColumnName = "Precio"

            Return dt

        Else
            Return Nothing

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

        Return Nothing
    Finally
        desconectado()
    End Try
End Function
```

En mi form ventas llamo a la función dentro de la clase fventa que anteriormente expuse.

```
    Private Sub mostrarProductosVentas()
    Try
        Dim func As New fventa
       'este dt lo declaro en el form ventas as new dataset
        dt = func.agregarProductosaVenta
        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try
End Sub
```

Y para finalizar en el evento textchanged de un textbox en el mismo form ventas llamo al sub mostrarProductosVentas.

He buscado por varios días y no logro solucionar esto, entiendo que tiene que ver algo con que estoy declarando un New Dataset pero no he podido arreglarlo, no entiendo que es lo que tengo que hacer

Comment: Creo que hay una forma mas sencilla. Defines las cabeceras de las columnas, luego, al recibir el `textbox.text` lo buscas en la BDD y recuperas el producto para agregarlo al DGV con datagridview1.rows.add (tus datos ordenados según las columnas). Luego, grabas la venta leyendo una a una las lineas del DGV... así lo hago yo al menos y funciona perfecto hace años....

Comment: Por otro lado no estoy seguro de esto: `If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery Then` `ExecuteNonQuery` devuelve un `int` con la cantidad de filas afectadas. Tal vez `If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery = 1 Then` sea la sentencia correcta.

Comment: Que tal Liyo,buen día. Antes que nada gracias por tu respuesta. La verdad que sigo con el mismo detalle que no he podido solucionar. O sea que vas grabando cada renglón a la base de datos mientras se van agregando al DGV?

Comment: Cuando generas de nuevo un dataset, Lo que haces es liberar el anterior y cargarlo con la nueva información que traes del SP en la BDD. Por ende, solo va a ser el último registro. Ahora te redacto una respuesta, para que sea mas claro lo que intento decirte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que te sugiero hacer, es generar un DataGridView con los encabezados de las columnas ya predefinidos, de la siguiente manera por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El DGV no tendrá filas, entonces lo que deberías hacer, es algo similar a esto:

```
'Generamos la consulta donde traemos los campos de la BDD según el codigo de barras ingresado
Dim codigo as String = txtcodBarras.text
Dim cant As Integer =txtcantidad.text 'si no tienes, puedes asignarlo a 1 u obviar este paso
Dim consulta as String= "SELECT descripcion, precio from productos where codigo = '" & codigo & "'"
'con sería la cadena de conexión
Using cmd = New MySqlCommand(consulta, con)
'Leemos con un reader los campos que necesitamos
    Using myReader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        Dim prod As String
        Dim precio As Double
        Dim preciof As Double
        While myReader.Read()
            prod = myReader("Descripcion")
            precio = myReader("Precio")
            preciof = precio * cant
        End While
        'Ahora vamos a llenar la fila del datagrid con los valores que trajimos
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(codigo, prod, cant, precio, preciof)
        'nos posicionamos en la última línea y hacemos scroll en el DGV hasta el final
        'para que siempre muestre el ultimo producto ingresado
        DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1).Selected = True
        DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    End Using
End Using
```

De esta manera vas a ir llenando el DGV fila por fila. Cuando finalizas la venta lo limpias con `DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()`

En este caso, utilizo la consulta directamente por código, pero bien es valido recuperar el producto de la BDD con un SP (yo no utilizo SP porque considero que desde el código es mas fácil y eficiente, pero ese es otro tema que nada tiene que ver con tu inconveniente :))

Espero te sea de utilidad, cualquier cosa que necesites me avisas y lo vemos.